Installing Packages to Virtual Environment in Google Colab
I am attempting to run my project in Google Colab. The project was developed on my local machine, where it operates flawlessly. To replicate the environment, I obtained a list of packages and their versions from my system, which I am now trying to install in the Google Colab notebook. However, this process has been fraught with persistent errors.
One particular issue arises when installing the python-dotenv package via pip. Despite following the recommendation to install it within a virtual environment, I encounter a No module named 'dotenv' error upon attempting to import it using from dotenv import load_dotenv.
What steps should I take to resolve this issue and successfully run my project in Google Colab?
I tried the following:

!pip install python-dotenv
!pip install python-dotenv==1.0.0
!python3 -m pip install 'python-dotenv==1.0.0'
!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall python-dotenv

The steps which I used to activate the Virtual Environment in Google Colab are as follows:


!pip install virtualenv



!virtualenv venv



!source venv/bin/activate




Actually you do not need install virtualenv in Google colab.
Just install the package you need.
!pip install package


This what I did before the virtual environment but it also did not work.
